# Join query in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I need to apply a join to 3 tables (invoice, payments, client) on the client ID; however, the join I need must include all the invoices and all the payments associated with a client ID. If we have a client that has a payment and no invoices (or the other way around) this column should also appear. I don't want duplicates in the resulting table, so if a client has both invoice and payment he should appear only once. I could use a cross join and then select distinct but is there a join that can do that directly.

Comment: please post your tablestructure

Comment: client ( client ID, preneurID, tot_DEBIT, TOT_CREDIT, TOTAL, ...) INVOICE (invoiceID, debit, date .....)
payment(payment ID, credit, date....)

how is it related to my question? I just need a join that will take all the rows from different tables, merge the ones with the same ID and keep the ones that are unique to a table

Comment: Very good! Now the other two tables, then maybe someone can help you... and please edit your question with the tablestructures and don't just add it as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
Select * From T1
left join T2 On T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID
Left join T3 On T1.ClientID = T3.ClientID
```

should do that.

Comment: I knew abouthe left outer join, but never heard (or forgot) about the left join. Thanks for your time

Comment: Left join is left outer join. Outer has been dropped/ deprecated  out of the syntax. Now inner join, left or right join, usually, depending on DBMS of course.

Comment: After reading, i noticed that the two are actualy similar i was the one who didn't understand their mechanism correctly. I always assumed it would only take the values of the left table that are unique to the left table.

Comment: That's an inner join. I believe the changed the syntax, because left and right are only relevant to outer joins.